# What is the typical approach taken for writing NSString objects to a file?

Tags: objective-c

As an example, I want to write out some string value, `str`, to a file, `"yy"`, as it changes through each iteration of a loop. Below is how I'm currently implementing it:

```
NSOutputStream *oStream = [[NSOutputStream alloc] initToFileAtPath:@"yy" append:NO];
[oStream open];

while ( ... )
{

    NSString *str = /* has already been set up */

    NSData *strData = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [oStream write:r(uint8_t *)[strData bytes] maxLength:[strData length]];

    ...
}

[oStream close];
```

Ignoring the UTF-8 encoding, which I do require, is this how `NSString`s are typically written to a file? That is, by first converting to an `NSData` object, then using `bytes` and casting the result to `uint8_t` for `NSOutputStream`'s `write`?

Are there alternatives that are used more often?

EDIT: Multiple `NSString`s need to be appended to the same file, hence the loop above.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

ctshryock's solution is a bit different than yours, since you're appending as you go, and ctshyrock's write a single file all at once (overwriting the previous version). For a long-running process, these are going to be radically different.

If you do want to write as you go, I typically use `NSFileHandle` here rather than `NSOutputStream`. It's just a little bit easier to use in my opinion.

```
NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:aPath];
while ( ... )
{
    NSString *str = /* has already been set up */

    [fileHandle writeData:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

[fileHandle closeFile];
```

Note that `fileHandle` will automatically close when it is dealloced, but I like to go ahead and close it explicitly when I'm done with it.

Comment: Is it also the case that fileHandleForWritingAtPath requires that the file already exists?

Comment: No, it will create a new file in any case (removing the old one if one already exists). See the NSFileHandle docs for details on other constructors that can append to existing files.

Comment: As a Cocoa beginner, I came here for information, tried this, and `fileHandleForWritingAtPath` consistently gave me `null` for nonexistent files. I had to use a POSIX `open()` with `O_CREAT` to create the file first. Does anyone have clarifying info on this, please?

Comment: I too had to create the file beforehand. I created the file using [NSFileManager createFileAtPath]

Answer (score 4):

I typically use NSString's methods `writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:` or `writeToURL:atomically:encoding:error:` for writing to file.

See the [String Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/readingFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003459) for more info

Comment: The question is not about one-shot writing, but rather incremental writing (appending) of a string to a file inside a loop.

Comment: really?  his question is "is this how NSStrings are typically written to a file".  his example doesn't quite match his question.